# Datetime value sent in AJAX call is not deserializing in MVC controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am sending a datetime string in following format '22/03/17' in side a javascript object . But in MVC controller this value is not serializing and it is giving null value. In the C# class the property is defined like this.

public DateTime? SubscriptionExpiryDate { get; set; }

What I am doing wrong.

javascript is like this

```
var data = self;

            ajaxRequest("POST", baseUrl + controller + "SaveSubcription", self)
                .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (data.Success == false) {

                        toastr.error('Problem in creating rule ', 'Error!')
                    }
                    else {
                        $(location).attr('href', baseUrl + "RuleEngine");
                        toastr.success('Rule saved successfully ', 'Success!');
                    }

                });
```

and Serializing class structure like this

public Guid SubscriptionId { get; set; }

```
    public Guid PlanId { get; set; }

    public Guid OrgId { get; set; }

    public decimal? PlanCost { get; set; }

    public decimal? AlrPlanCost { get; set; }

    public DateTime? SubscriptionStartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? SubscriptionExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: show you javascript, cshtml, action code

Comment: @JaiminDave updated the code

Comment: @Utpal- Try sending it in yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: .Net is trying to convert your date '22/03/17' to 'MM/DD/YY' default format and since it fails during conversion, it simply assigns the value to null. You need to convert this value to mm/dd/yy format using Moment.js or other powerful client libraries before hitting API as even Date() JS function won't recognize 'DD/MM/YY' format.

Answer (score 0):

May your system date time format is not proper or you have to set culture in your MVC controller , so that it will get the value at the time of serialization